# Install Wmware tools on Debian

Tags: debian, vmware, clipboard

I can't copy/paste from Vmware virtual machine with 32-bit Debian inside of it to my Windows 8. I decided to install VM tools. After mounting the VM media to `/media/cdrom0` I got the contents :

```
dr-xr-xr-x 2 root root     2048 Oct 17  2013 . drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Feb 25 12:30 ..
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root     1961 Oct 17  2013 manifest.txt
-r--r--r-- 1 root root     1847 Oct 17  2013 run_upgrader.sh
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 60638465 Oct 17  2013 VMwareTools-9.6.1-1378637.tar.gz
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root   689456 Oct 17  2013 vmware-tools-upgrader-32
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root   702472 Oct 17  2013 vmware-tools-upgrader-64
```

Then I copied it to home and

```
chmod +x run_upgrader.sh
```

After executing `run_upgrader.sh` I got nothing on screen, but copy/paste still does not works.

How to solve this problem?

VMware version 10.0.1 build-1379776

Comment: run_upgrader outputs to `/var/log/vmware-tools-upgrader.log
`. Are there any errors in it?

Comment: Please confirm the title of your question (Wmware).